# .push is not a function node js

Tags: javascript

friends,
I have a problem to run this code

node js (cmd)

```
var addnote = (title, body) => {
  var notes = [];
  var note = {
    title,
    body
  };

var notestring  = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
notes = JSON.parse(notestring);

notes.push(note);
fs.writeFileSync('notes-data.json', JSON.stringify(notes));
}
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: A) What error do you get? B) What does `notes-data.json` contain? If it's not an array you can't `push`.

Answer (score 0):

You first define notes as an array

```
var notes = [];
```

But then overwrite this variable with

```
notes = JSON.parse(notestring);
```

JSON.parse will set notes equal to an object rather than an array. Therefore it has no push method. If you are trying to use an array in the 'notes-data.json' file you may access it like so:

```
notes = JSON.parse(notestring).nameOfMyArray;
```

Edit:

As a cool tip, you can rewrite

```
var notestring  = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
notes = JSON.parse(notestring);
```

As

```
var notesData = require('notes-data.json');
```

The require method will parse the json for you.

Answer (score 0):

If `notes-data.json` is an object and not an array, you can't push to an object.